# SQLITE - JDBC error near 'ORDER'

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

I am running an update statement that works perfectly fine in sqlite but failed with jdbc.

command:

```
UPDATE BKPSERVER set BKP_STATUS = 'S' 
where CLIENT_IP = '192.168.0.16' AND BKP_STATUS='R' 
ORDER BY ROWID DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

But using jdbc it fails with the following statement.

```
enter coException in thread "main" org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "ORDER": syntax error)
```

Please advise what I can do to fix this as it simply makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the syntax diagram for [SQLite's UPDATE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html):

[image]

you should notice that there is no mention of an ORDER BY clause. Including an ORDER BY in an UPDATE really doesn't make much sense anyway: you're updating a *set* of records so there's nothing to order, similarly for the LIMIT clause. You should say:

```
UPDATE BKPSERVER set BKP_STATUS = 'S' where CLIENT_IP = '192.168.0.16' AND BKP_STATUS='R';
```

If there are multiple records with that `CLIENT_IP` and `BKP_STATUS` then you'll have to find the unique one some other way, perhaps a subquery:

```
UPDATE BKPSERVER
set BKP_STATUS = 'S'
where rowid = (
    select rowid
    from BKPSERVER
    where CLIENT_IP = '192.168.0.16'
      AND BKP_STATUS='R'
    ORDER BY ROWID DESC
    LIMIT 1
);
```

---

Some versions of SQLite are built with the `SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT` flag set so the `UPDATE` does support `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`; for those SQLite builds, `UPDATE` looks like:

[image]

but it seems that your SQLite is not built with this flag enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
UPDATE BKPSERVER
set    BKP_STATUS = 'S'
where  CLIENT_IP = '192.168.0.16'
   AND BKP_STATUS='R' 
   AND ROWID = (  SELECT  MAX(ROWID)
                  FROM    BKPSERVER b2
                  where   b2.CLIENT_IP = '192.168.0.16'
                      AND b2.BKP_STATUS='R')
```

Comment: Great suggestion above but not working yet I will continue working on this

Comment: @gcclinux I can't see any reason why this wouldn't have worked. What error message or incorrect behaviour did you get?